# html form data is not inserting in MySQL database using PHP and PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

since  i am new new here,i'm trying to be specific on my question. please tell me if you need more info.

Whenever i'm trying to submit the form it doesn't show any error regarding the code. it only show echo statement "FAILED"

i am using this loop to see if the values are submitted or not. this is working fine. it shows that all the values are submitted but these values are not inserting into database .

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "($key) => ($value)<br/>";
}
```

my html form code is :

```
        <div class="formstyle">
        <h2> Sign up </h2>
<center>
<form method = 'POST' name="form1" onSubmit="return validateForm()" action="">

   <table border='0'>
 <tr>
  <td><LABEL for="firstname">First Name:<sup style="color:#F00">*</sup> </LABEL></td>
         <td><INPUT type="text" name = "fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>"></td><td width="200px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointfn"></i></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><LABEL for="lastname">Last Name:<sup style="color:#F00">*</sup> </LABEL></td>
  <td><INPUT type="text" name ="lname" id="lname" value="<?php echo $lname;?>"> </td><td width="200px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointln"></i></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td><LABEL for="gender">Gender:<sup style="color:#F00">*</sup> </LABEL></td> <td>
   <INPUT type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male"> Male
   <INPUT type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female"> Female</td><td width="200px"> <i style="color:red;" id="pointgendr"></i></td>
 </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><LABEL for="email">Email:<sup style="color:red;">*</sup> </LABEL></td>
  <td><INPUT type="text" name = "email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"></td><td width="200px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointemail"></i></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td><LABEL for="password">Password:<sup style="color:#F00">*</sup> </LABEL></td>
  <td><INPUT type="password" name ="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>"></td><td width="200px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointpassword"></i></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td></td><td><br/><INPUT type="submit" name = "register" value="Create Account">
  <INPUT type="reset" onClick="return confirmreset()"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td></td><td style="font-size:12px;text-align:right;"><br/><i style="color:red;font-size:12px;align:right;" >* - Mandatory</i></td>
 </tr>
    </table>

     </form></center>
```

this is the php code that inserting everything into database

```
    require('connect.php');

$fname = $lname = $gender = $email = $password = "";

if(isset($_POST['register'])){

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user(fname,lname,gender,email,password)
    VALUES (:fname, :lname, :gender, :email, :password)');
    $stmt->bindValue(':fname',$fname);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lname',$lname);
    $stmt->bindValue(':gender',$gender);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email',$email);
    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));
    $stmt->bindValue(':password',$passwordHash);
    $stmt->execute();


    $email_stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = :email");
    $email_stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $email_stmt->execute();

    if ($email_stmt->rowCount()>0){
        echo 'Email Already Exists. Use Different Email OR Login ';
        } else {
        //Successful Registration 
        echo 'Registration Successful';
    } 
} else {
    echo 'FAILED';
}

?>
```

any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Are those your variables?  Your variable initializations for your post seems sketchy

Comment: That would suggest that `isset($_POST['register'])` is empty. What value do you see for this?

Comment: @Akintunde yes all these are variables. it says all of them are empty at the moment  $fname = $lname = $gender = $email = $password =

Comment: @Andy All those values fname,lname,gender,email and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are checking if email taken after using insert

try this

```
 if(isset($_POST['register'])){

    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));

    //validate form here

    $email_stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = :email");
    $email_stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $email_stmt->execute();
    $result = $email_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (empty($result)) {

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user(fname,lname,gender,email,password)
        VALUES (:fname, :lname, :gender, :email, :password)');
        $stmt->bindValue(':fname',$fname);
        $stmt->bindValue(':lname',$lname);
        $stmt->bindValue(':gender',$gender);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email',$email);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password',$passwordHash);


        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            echo 'Registration Successful';
            }

            else {
                echo 'FAILED';
        } 
    }   


    else {
       echo 'Email Already Exists. Use Different Email OR Login ';

    } 
}
```

Comment: i tried your given code. It seemed super legit to me . but it didn't showed any message weather it is successful or failed. i think $stmt is not executing. but i am not sure. i new to this.

Comment: the error that you found about email checking is true. i am also working on that but no luck so far

Comment: post any error message if you get, i tested it again worked fine

Comment: so , I've tried your code different times and it worked finally. here is the code that i've implemented , there was one if statement for email .
    
if ($email_stmt->rowCount()>0){
  echo 'Email Already Exists. Use Different Email OR Login ';
  }

Comment: glad i could help Arch :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't need a foreach for this form. I think you should try for example:

```
echo  $_POST['fname'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Also this `name = "fname"` should be this `name="fname"`

Comment: it says Undefined index: fname , and all other variables

Answer (score 0):

You must put POST'S into variables.
Try this

```
    require('connect.php');

$fname = $lname = $gender = $email = $password = "";

if(isset($_POST['register'])){

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user(fname,lname,gender,email,password)
    VALUES (:fname, :lname, :gender, :email, :password)');
    $stmt->bindValue(':fname',$fname);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lname',$lname);
    $stmt->bindValue(':gender',$gender);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email',$email);
    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));
    $stmt->bindValue(':password',$passwordHash);
    $stmt->execute();


    $email_stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = :email");
    $email_stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $email_stmt->execute();

    if ($email_stmt->rowCount()>0){
        echo 'Email Already Exists. Use Different Email OR Login ';
        } else {
        //Successful Registration 
        echo 'Registration Successful';
    } 
} else {
    echo 'FAILED';
}

?>
```

Comment: it says all the variables are undefined and a  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

Comment: @Arsh probably you already have the same email registered in database. If you can, clear you database data first. (for better understanding post the entire error message)

Comment: yeah i needed to put POSTS in the variables . it worked when i added POST where i was binding two values. Thank you :)